# Preventing a $(window).on('scroll function) from firing until after a .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I do not want `$(window).on('scroll', function() {}` to begin until after  `$('#load_more_photos').on('click', function() {}` has already been run. I want to achieve Instagram-like pagination that begins with the button being clicked and transitions into scrolling pagination. Also, I would like to add a time transition so that each pagination takes 1500ms, right now I feel that the photos are loading too fast on scroll and it is awkward.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $('.pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos').show();
    $('#load_more_photos').on('click', function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(url);
      $('#load_more_photos').hide();   
    });  
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60 && $.active == 0) {
        $.getScript(url);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

**Edit:** I tried to add a boolean below but it is not working, the click function does not work at all.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  var clicked_yet;
  clicked_yet = true;  
  if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $('.pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos').show();
    $('#load_more_photos').on('click', function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(url);
      $('#load_more_photos').hide();
      clicked_yet = false;
    });  
    if (!clicked_yet) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60 && $.active == 0) {
        $.getScript(url);
        }
    });
    }
  }  
});
```

Comment: either load the event onclick or use a Boolean that is set when a click happens.

Comment: @epascarello I tried to add a boolean please see edit above but still not working.

Comment: Use the condition `if (!clicked_yet) {` inside the scroll function...

Comment: @Hackerman still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this code working after rolling back the code. There might have been css issues somewhere in the code previously. It works as intended now.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $('.pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos').show();
    $('#load_more_photos').on('click', function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(url);
      $('#load_more_photos').hide();   
      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60 && $.active == 0) {
        $.getScript(url);
        }
    });
    });  
  }
});
```

Comment: `$.active == 0` saved me a lot of time.